# Python Dash DataTable with data bars conditional formating

Tags: python, if-statement, datatable, conditional-formatting, plotly-dash

I am new to python and plotly dash. I saw the code that displays horizontal bar charts within the table.
I want the bar to change color depending on another column. For example, I want to change the color of the bar in column "tip" depending on "day" column. But I don't know where to put the if statement or filter query in my code, can anyone teach me how to do it?

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/tips.csv')

def data_bars(df, column):
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    ranges = [
        ((df[column].max() - df[column].min()) * i) + df[column].min()
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #0074D9 0%,
                    #0074D9 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    sort_action='native',
    columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=(
        data_bars(df, 'tip')

    ),
    style_cell={
        'width': '100px',
        'minWidth': '100px',
        'maxWidth': '100px',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
    },
    page_size=20
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple conditions based on the day.
For example (in this case the bar will be colored in blue in case the day is not Saturday, and in case the day is Saturday then it will be colored in red):

```py
# In case the day is not Saturday
styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound) + ' && {day} != Sat',
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #0074D9 0%,
                    #0074D9 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })
# In case the day is Saturday
styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound) + ' && {day} = Sat',
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #ff0000 0%,
                    #ff0000 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })
```

Comment: Thank you Yahav! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @PhilipH If this answer solved your problem, please accept it as verified (the green vee) and vote it up so that other users can relay on it.